# Attempted to load sdk version 5.0.397 on page, but window.paypal at version undefined already loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

I am using "@paypal/react-paypal-js": "^7.8.3", to integrate paypal with my frontend in react. I have a component which shows paypal's button on popup here is the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import PopupWrapper from "./PopupWrapper";

import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

const options = {
  "client-id":
    "AeARNmB6nLWPSPtzITkcfVqjueDuwfPSYkV2qcquQ23zhn-z07e-RdAPgypoRjth_jXzt7qXVm-VCPhO",
  currency: "USD",
  intent: "capture",
};

const PaypalPopup = ({ open, setOpen, onApprove, createOrder }) => {
  return (
    <PopupWrapper open={open} setOpen={setOpen}>
      <div className="mt-12">
        <PayPalScriptProvider options={options}>
          <PayPalButtons
            style={{ layout: "vertical" }}
            onApprove={onApprove}
            createOrder={createOrder}
          />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
      </div>
    </PopupWrapper>
  );
};

export default PaypalPopup;
```

, but whenever i open the popup it says the following error:

"Attempted to load sdk version 5.0.397 on page, but window.paypal at version undefined already loaded. To load this sdk alongside the existing version, please specify a different namespace in the script tag, e.g. , then use the paypal_sdk namespace in place of paypal in your code."

I tried to take the PayPalScriptProvider component and wrapped it around the app component in the index.js file, by this the error went away if i reload on any other page than /checkout and then moved to checkout the paypal works fine, but if i reload on the /checkout page and then click on paynow which opens the pop up i am getting the error again.